# Error with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I must be an idiot, because this is my 3rd question for today. 
Here's my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

include("mainmenu.php");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "********");
 if(!$con){
  die(mysql_error());
}

$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

mysql_select_db("`users`, $con) or die(mysql_error()");

$query = ("INSERT INTO `users`.`data` (`id`, `usrname`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `password`) 
VALUES (NULL, '$usrname', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', 'password'))");

mysql_query('$query') or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);

echo("Thank you for registering!");
```

I always get the error returned as: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query' at line 1.
Help a newbie. I'm about to stab my monitor.

Comment: remove the quotes from mysql_query('$query')

Comment: not a very helpful title

Comment: haha you guys voted down my noob question

Comment: You forgot `mysql_real_escape_string`. Usually this indicates learning from a very very very bad tutorial or book. Throw it away.

Comment: Burn the book. Scatter the ashes. Use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) On this line:

```
mysql_select_db("`users`, $con) or die(mysql_error()");
```

Should be:

```
mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Right now you have PHP code inside the string you're sending as the database name.

2) On this line:

```
mysql_query('$query');
```

By using single quotes, the literal string `$query` will be sent rather than the contents of a variable called `$query`. Use either `mysql_query($query)` or `mysql_query("$query");`

Also, where you create `$query`, and where you `echo` the success message, the parentheses around the string are unnecessary.

WITHIN `$query`, you have too many closing parentheses. You also fail to escape any of the input, so if someone writes something nasty in your form (like anything with a single quote character), it'll break your query.

Comment: OMG! THANX SO MUCH! (told you i was a noob)

Comment: -1 for not pointing out mysql_real_escape_string or SQL-inject issues in this dangerous code.

Comment: Except I did point that out... 3 months ago... that's the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: sorry for being a blind bat you did, missed your comment somehow.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

uneeded quotes around your $query variable.

single quotes (') do not allow you to embed variables, while double quotes (") do.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query('$query') => mysql_query("$query")

Answer (score 1):

**How to fix the SQL-injection hole**

Change this code

[image]**coding horror**

```
$usrname = $_POST['usrname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

Into this

```
$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usrname']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```